# Convert size notation with units (100kb, 32MB) to number of bytes in Python

Tags: python, type-conversion

I need to convert a human readable notation of the upload size limit (e.g. 100kb,32MB, etc.) using Python. The converted value should be expressed as a number of bytes.

**Example**

```
convert_size_to_bytes("32MB") # should return 33554432
convert_size_to_bytes("100kB") # should return 102400
convert_size_to_bytes("123B") # should return 123
convert_size_to_bytes("123") # should return 123
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I liked the simple approach taken by @Robson, but I noticed it has a number of corner cases that it didn't handle. The version below is largely the same, but it adds/fixes the following:

- Adds support for byte, kilobyte, etc.
- Provides support for singular units, e.g., "1 byte"
- Adds support for yottabytes, zetabytes, etc. The version above would crash for these.
- Adds support for spaces before, after, and in the input.
- Adds support for floats ("5.2 mb")
- Bigger docstring

Here's the code:

```
def convert_size_to_bytes(size_str):
    """Convert human filesizes to bytes.

    Special cases:
     - singular units, e.g., "1 byte"
     - byte vs b
     - yottabytes, zetabytes, etc.
     - with & without spaces between & around units.
     - floats ("5.2 mb")

    To reverse this, see hurry.filesize or the Django filesizeformat template
    filter.

    :param size_str: A human-readable string representing a file size, e.g.,
    "22 megabytes".
    :return: The number of bytes represented by the string.
    """
    multipliers = {
        'kilobyte':  1024,
        'megabyte':  1024 ** 2,
        'gigabyte':  1024 ** 3,
        'terabyte':  1024 ** 4,
        'petabyte':  1024 ** 5,
        'exabyte':   1024 ** 6,
        'zetabyte':  1024 ** 7,
        'yottabyte': 1024 ** 8,
        'kb': 1024,
        'mb': 1024**2,
        'gb': 1024**3,
        'tb': 1024**4,
        'pb': 1024**5,
        'eb': 1024**6,
        'zb': 1024**7,
        'yb': 1024**8,
    }

    for suffix in multipliers:
        size_str = size_str.lower().strip().strip('s')
        if size_str.lower().endswith(suffix):
            return int(float(size_str[0:-len(suffix)]) * multipliers[suffix])
    else:
        if size_str.endswith('b'):
            size_str = size_str[0:-1]
        elif size_str.endswith('byte'):
            size_str = size_str[0:-4]
    return int(size_str)
```

And I wrote a bunch of tests for values that we're scraping:

```
class TestFilesizeConversions(TestCase):

    def test_filesize_conversions(self):
        """Can we convert human filesizes to bytes?"""
        qa_pairs = [
            ('58 kb', 59392),
            ('117 kb', 119808),
            ('117kb', 119808),
            ('1 byte', 1),
            ('117 bytes', 117),
            ('117  bytes', 117),
            ('  117 bytes  ', 117),
            ('117b', 117),
            ('117bytes', 117),
            ('1 kilobyte', 1024),
            ('117 kilobytes', 119808),
            ('0.7 mb', 734003),
            ('1mb', 1048576),
            ('5.2 mb', 5452595),
        ]
        for qa in qa_pairs:
            print("Converting '%s' to bytes..." % qa[0], end='')
            self.assertEqual(convert_size_to_bytes(qa[0]), qa[1])
            print('✓')
```

Comment: The terminology for these units [has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69679309/217867).

Comment: Has it? Depends on your audience. If I say kibobytes to anybody that doesn't use Stackoverflow, they'll look at me like I'm crazy.

Answer (score 3):

The following function does the job:

```
def convert_size_to_bytes(size):
    multipliers = {
        'kb': 1024,
        'mb': 1024*1024,
        'gb': 1024*1024*1024,
        'tb': 1024*1024*1024*1024
    }

    for suffix in multipliers:
        if size.lower().endswith(suffix):
            return int(size[0:-len(suffix)]) * multipliers[suffix]
    else:
        if size.lower().endswith('b'):
            return int(size[0:-1])

    try:
        return int(size)
    except ValueError: # for example "1024x"
        print('Malformed input!')
        exit()

print(convert_size_to_bytes("32MB"))
print(convert_size_to_bytes("100kB"))
print(convert_size_to_bytes("123B"))
print(convert_size_to_bytes("123"))
```

You can test this function here: http://ideone.com/kse773

This function requires improvements to support a single character size units (e.g. `B` for bytes). As `B` is a suffix of the `kB` different approach should by applied.

Comment: this is one of these rare cases where an `else` on the `for` loop would make sense to capture the single `b`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thank you for confirmation that `else` on the `for` loop is acceptable here. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: And to make it full-proof you might want to encapsulate the last `return` in a `try` block like: [this](http://ideone.com/BMDb0V)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I've modified my code in the answer and on the Ideone.

Answer (score 3):

an alternative using regular expression and replacement functions:

```
import re

suffixes = "","k","m","g","t"
multipliers = {'{}b'.format(l) : 1024**i for i,l in enumerate(suffixes) }

sre = re.compile("(\d+)({})".format("|".join(x+"b" for x in suffixes)),re.IGNORECASE)

def subfunc(m):
    return str(int(m.group(1))*multipliers[m.group(2).lower()])

def convert_size_to_bytes(size):
    return sre.sub(subfunc,size)


print(convert_size_to_bytes("32MB"))
print(convert_size_to_bytes("100kB"))
print(convert_size_to_bytes("123"))
```

The dictionary and the regexes are generated according to the unit (so it can be extended to exa, peta...)

When matching digits + unit, it replaces the expression by the evaluated integer for the first group times the value of the dictionary), converted back to string as the `re.sub` function requires.